# not able to receive sms, Help me correct the code

Tags: java-me, sms, lwuit, midp, wma

I don't know what is the problem, but SMS is not received with below code and when I see in the phone memory, app is invalid.

Can anyone correct this code?
I am having a lot of issues with this, it compiles well, but when it is on the real phone, the app says it is invalid,[Nokia 2630 supports MIDP 2.0](http://www.phonescoop.com/phones/phone.php?p=1262), so not a phone problem.

```
package Pushtest;

import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionEvent;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionListener;
import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.GridLayout;
import javax.microedition.io.*;
import javax.wireless.messaging.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.*;

/**
* @author test
*/
public class SendApprooval extends MIDlet implements Runnable, ActionListener, MessageListener {

  Date todaydate;

  private Dialog content, alert;
  Thread thread;
  String[] connections;
  boolean done;
  String senderAddress, mess;
  MessageConnection smsconn = null, clientConn = null;
  Message msg;

 // public SendApprooval() {
/*       
        smsPort = getAppProperty("SMS-Port");
        content = new Dialog("");
        content.addComponent(new Label("Waiting for Authentication Request"));
        content.setDialogType(Dialog.TYPE_INFO);
        content.setTimeout(2000);
     //   exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 2);
     //  content.addCommand(exitCommand)
        content.addCommand(exitCommand);
        content.addCommandListener(this);
        content.show(); 
        }  */

        public void startApp() {

         Display.init(this);

        String smsConnection = "sms://:" + 5000;
        if (smsconn == null) {
              try {
                    smsconn = (MessageConnection) Connector.open(smsConnection);
                    smsconn.setMessageListener(this);
              } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
              }
        }
        connections = PushRegistry.listConnections(true);
        if ((connections == null) || (connections.length == 0)) {
              content.addComponent(new Label("Waiting for Authentication Request"));
        }
        done = false;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
  //      display.setCurrent(resumeScreen);

  }

  public void run() {
        try {
              msg = smsconn.receive();
              if (msg != null) {
                    senderAddress = msg.getAddress();
                    int k, j = 0;
                    for (k = 0; k <= senderAddress.length() - 1; k++) {
                          if (senderAddress.charAt(k) == ':') {
                                j++;
                                if (j == 2) {
                                      break;
                                }
                          }
                    }
                    senderAddress = senderAddress.substring(0, k + 1);
                    content.addComponent(new Label(senderAddress));
                    senderAddress = senderAddress + 5000;
                    if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
                          mess = ((TextMessage) msg).getPayloadText();
                    } 
                    else {
                          StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                          byte[] data = ((BinaryMessage) msg).getPayloadData();
                          for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                int intData = (int) data[i] & 0xFF;
                                if (intData < 0x10) {
                                      buf.append("0");
                                }
                                buf.append(Integer.toHexString(intData));
                                buf.append(' ');
                          }
                          mess = buf.toString();
                    }
                    if (mess.equals("Give me Rights")) {
                          try {
                                clientConn = (MessageConnection) Connector.open(senderAddress);
                          }catch (Exception e) {
                                alert = new Dialog("Alert");
                                alert.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
                                alert.addComponent(new Label("Unable to connect to Station because of network problem"));
                                alert.setTimeout(2000);
                                alert.setDialogType(Dialog.TYPE_INFO);
                                Display.init(alert);
                                alert.show();
                          }
                          try {
                                TextMessage textmessage = (TextMessage) clientConn.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
                                textmessage.setAddress(senderAddress);
                                textmessage.setPayloadText("Approoved");
                                clientConn.send(textmessage);
                          } catch (Exception e) {
                                Dialog alert = new Dialog("");
                                alert.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
                                alert.setDialogType(Dialog.TYPE_INFO);
                                alert.setTimeout(2000);
                                alert.addComponent(new Label(e.toString()));
                                Display.init(alert);
                                alert.show();
                          }
                    }
              } else {
              }
        } catch (IOException e) {
              content.addComponent(new Label(e.toString()));
              Display.init(content);
        }
  }

  public void pauseApp() {
        done = true;
        thread = null;
        Display.init(this);
  }

  public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
        done = true;
        thread = null;
        if (smsconn != null) {
              try {
              smsconn.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
              }
              notifyDestroyed();
        }
  }

  public void showMessage(String message, Display displayable) {
        Dialog alert = new Dialog("");
        alert.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.addComponent(new Label(message));
        alert.setDialogType(Dialog.TYPE_ERROR);
        alert.setTimeout(5000);
        alert.show();
  }


  public void notifyIncomingMessage(MessageConnection conn) {
        if (thread == null) {
              content.addComponent(new Label("Waiting for Authentication Request"));
              content.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
              content.setDialogType(Dialog.TYPE_INFO);
              content.show();
              done = false;
              thread = new Thread(this);
              thread.start();

        }
  }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {


       System.out.println("Event fired" + ae.getCommand().getCommandName());
    int id = ae.getCommand().getId();
    Command cmd = ae.getCommand();
    String cmdName1 = cmd.getCommandName();
     try {
              msg = smsconn.receive();
              if (msg != null) {
                    senderAddress = msg.getAddress();
                    int k, j = 0;
                    for (k = 0; k <= senderAddress.length() - 1; k++) {
                          if (senderAddress.charAt(k) == ':') {
                                j++;
                                if (j == 2) {
                                      break;
                                }
                          }
                    }
                    senderAddress = senderAddress.substring(0, k + 1);
                    content.addComponent(new Label(senderAddress));
                    senderAddress = senderAddress + 5000;
                    if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
                          mess = ((TextMessage) msg).getPayloadText();
                    } 
                    else {
                          StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                          byte[] data = ((BinaryMessage) msg).getPayloadData();
                          for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                int intData = (int) data[i] & 0xFF;
                                if (intData < 0x10) {
                                      buf.append("0");
                                }
                                buf.append(Integer.toHexString(intData));
                                buf.append(' ');
                          }
                          mess = buf.toString();
                    }
                    if (mess.equals("Give me Rights")) {
                          try {
                                clientConn = (MessageConnection) Connector.open(senderAddress);
                          }catch (Exception e) {
                                alert = new Dialog("Alert");
                                alert.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
                                alert.addComponent(new Label("Unable to connect to Station because of network problem"));
                                alert.setTimeout(2000);
                                alert.setDialogType(Dialog.TYPE_INFO);
                                Display.init(alert);
                                alert.show();
                          }
                          try {
                                TextMessage textmessage = (TextMessage) clientConn.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
                                textmessage.setAddress(senderAddress);
                                textmessage.setPayloadText("Approoved");
                                clientConn.send(textmessage);
                          } catch (Exception e) {
                                Dialog alert = new Dialog("");
                                alert.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
                                alert.setDialogType(Dialog.TYPE_INFO);
                                alert.setTimeout(2000);
                                alert.addComponent(new Label(e.toString()));
                                Display.init(alert);
                                alert.show();
                          }
                    }
              } else {
              }
              if (("Exit").equals(cmdName1)) {
              destroyApp(true);
              notifyDestroyed();
              }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be cause because your sending SMS might not send on the port you defined in your code,

Please look at to this working [example](http://jimmod.com/blog/2011/02/jimmys-blog-send-receiving-on-specific-port-with-j2me-application/).

Comment: yes mate, i used the same code to send sms, its still not receiving,exact same code to send sms.

Comment: are you trying on phone or emulator ?

Comment: i am trying on the phone, m placing the jar and jad files into phone memory and trying,

Answer (score 0):

i found it guys, Thanks for your support, i'm sure i would come back with more queries, i have written a sample receiving sms code with port 5000, It would Help someone in someway,
Before you start, 
Right click your application in netbeans and select properties. Now select the application descriptor. select the attribute tab and select the Add button. Give the following in the corresponding fields.
Name : SMS-Port
Value : portno
Now u have registered the port no successfully.

Now again select the push registry tab.
give the following in the corresponding fields.
Class Name : Package name.class name
Sender ip : *
Connection String: sms://:portno
Now u have registered the push registry successfully.

CODE HERE:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends MIDlet implements ActionListener, MessageListener {

    private Form formReceiver;
    private TextField tfPort;
        private MessageConnection msgConnection;
    private MessageListener Listener;
    private String port;



    protected void destroyApp(boolean unconditional)
            throws MIDletStateChangeException {

    }

    protected void pauseApp() {

    }

    protected void startApp() {
            Display.init(this);

        try {
            Resources r = Resources.open("/m21.res");

            UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(
                    r.getTheme(r.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    formReceiver = new Form();
        formReceiver.setTitle(" ");
        formReceiver.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
        formReceiver.setTransitionInAnimator(null);
        TextField.setReplaceMenuDefault(false);

        Label lblPort = new Label("Port");
        tfPort = new TextField();
        tfPort.setMaxSize(8);
        tfPort.setUseSoftkeys(false);
        tfPort.setHeight(10);
        tfPort.setConstraint(TextField.DECIMAL);
        formReceiver.addComponent(lblPort);
        formReceiver.addComponent(tfPort);
        formReceiver.addCommand(new Command("Listen"), 0);
        formReceiver.addCommand(new Command("Exit"), 0);
        formReceiver.addCommandListener(this);

        formReceiver.show();
    }



    public void notifyIncomingMessage(MessageConnection conn) {
        Message message;
        try {
            message = conn.receive();
            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                TextMessage tMessage = (TextMessage)message;
                formReceiver.addComponent(new Label("Message received : "+tMessage.getPayloadText()+"\n"));
            } else {
                formReceiver.addComponent(new Label("Unknown Message received\n"));
            }
        } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
       System.out.println("Event fired" + ae.getCommand().getCommandName());
        int idi = ae.getCommand().getId();
        Command cmd = ae.getCommand();
        String cmdNam = cmd.getCommandName();
        if ("Listen".equals(cmdNam)) {
              ListenSMS sms = new ListenSMS(tfPort.getSelectCommandText(), this);
            sms.start();
        }
        if ("Exit".equals(cmdNam)) {
              notifyDestroyed();
        }
        }
    }


class ListenSMS extends Thread {
    private MessageConnection msgConnection;
    private MessageListener Listener;
    private String port;

    public ListenSMS(String port, MessageListener listener) {
        this.port = port;
        this.Listener = listener;
    }



    public void run() {
        try {
            msgConnection = (MessageConnection)Connector.open("sms://:" + 5000);
            msgConnection.setMessageListener(Listener);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```